# Understanding the "Struct" in Unity ParticleSystem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, struct, particle-system

The code below is working, "Particle" is an instance of class "ParticleSystem".

"Particle.emission" is a **get-only property** return struct "ParticleSystem.EmissionModule"

"em.rate" is a property, the type is struct "ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve"

```
ParticleSystem.EmissionModule em = Particle.emission; 
em.rate = new ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve(5);
```

My problem is, why the code above can change the rate in "Particle" instance?

Note the struct is not reference, so it cannot be changed directly, or it will cause [CS1612](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wydkhw2c.aspx)

Currently, my guess is the struct "ParticleSystem.EmissionModule" stored some references that can link or relate to the original "Particle" instance?

Comment: It's very hard to tell without a complete example - are you *certain* that `EmissionModule` is a struct? And that if you use `Particle.emission.rate` you'll see the new rate?

Comment: Yes, I am certain, so that why I can provide their type and describe this problem.

Comment: How have you ascertained that changing `rate` actually changes the emission rate for `Particle`? What happens if you log the values of `Particle.emission.rate` before and after the change you make?

Comment: Changed, originally is 10, after is 5

Comment: Are you able to see that just by logging `Particle.emission.rate` before and after though? It's possible that `EmissionModule` has a reference back to the `Particle` it comes from, but that would certainly seem odd...

Comment: @JonSkeet I dug into this and found out that there is a `ParticleSystem` reference saved into a temporary variable in the `EmissionModule` . That variable is then controlled by the rate `rate` property variable. Feel free to modify my answer if anything looks wrong.

Comment: How truly horrible. Violates all expectations...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I noticed this behavior too but I found out what's happening after digging deeper with .NET Reflector.

The complete example of your code with the latest Unity version:

```
ParticleSystem particle = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
ParticleSystem.EmissionModule em = particle.emission;
em.rate = new ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve(5);
```

Things to bear in mind:

`ParticleSystem`  is a `class`.

`EmissionModule` is a `struct`.

To change the Particle's emission rate in Unity 5 and above, you must get the [`ParticleSystem.emission`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem-emission.html) then store it in a temporary [`EmissionModule`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.EmissionModule.html)(struct) then you can modify it's [`rate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.EmissionModule-rate.html) variable

**How does this work?**

***When you do***:

```
ParticleSystem particle = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
```

or create/instantiate new `ParticleSystem` or attach one through the Editor, Unity will create new `EmissionModule` instance. `EmissionModule` has a an `internal` constructor that takes `ParticleSystem` as a parameter. Unity will immediately pass the current `ParticleSystem` instance to this `EmissionModule` constructor and that instance is stored in a temporary variable in the `EmissionModule` struct for later use.

It looks something like this:

```
private ParticleSystem tempParticleSystem;
internal EmissionModule(ParticleSystem particleInstance)
{
    this.tempParticleSystem = particleInstance;
}
```

***When you do***:

```
ParticleSystem.EmissionModule em = particle.emission;
```

Unity will create new instance of `EmissionModule` from the current particle (`particle`) and return it. That will contain that `ParticleSystem` (tempParticleSystem) reference that was saved. Remember that `ParticleSystem` is a class, so the reference is still there. The [`emission`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem-emission.html) property only have the `get` accessor. No `set` accessor. Because of this, it is a *read* only property.

The [`emission`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem-emission.html) property looks something like this:

```
public EmissionModule emission
{
    get
    {
        return new EmissionModule(this);
    }
}
```

***Finally, when the you do***:

```
em.rate = ....
```

or change the emission rate, that saved reference is used to change the Particle rate in the native side of Unity which is written in C++.

```
public ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve rate
{
    get
    {
        ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve curve = new ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve();
        getParticleRate(this.tempParticleSystem, ref curve);
        return curve;
    }
    set
    {
        setParticleRate(this.tempParticleSystem, ref value);
    }
}
```

To simplify this, we can call this a result of a `class` (`ParticleSystem`) inside a `struct` (`EmissionModule`).

Comment: Thanks, this also how I guessed before,  struct "EmissionModule" store the reference of particle class!

Comment: Yup that was the first thing I thought too. Wanted to verify before posting and it turns out to be true after using Reflector to check it.