# Vector3.Set and Rigidbody2D.velocity.Set and function not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, properties

In a simple movement script where `body` is `gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ()`, movement is applied by this code

```
body.velocity = new Vector2 (10 * dir, body.velocity.y);
```

However in this one no movement (nor error) appears

```
body.velocity.Set (10 * dir, body.velocity.y);
```

I see no explanation in [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html). Can you explain why `body.velocity.x` remains zero in the second case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the mistakes people make while using Unity.
You have to understand C# well to know what's really happening and why.

Here is why:

**1**.`Rigidbody.velocity` and `Rigidbody2D.velocity` are both types of `Vector3` and `Vector2`.

**2**.`Vector3` and `Vector2`  are both `structs` not `class`.

See `struct` vs `class` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net) for more info.

**3**.`Rigidbody.velocity` and `Rigidbody2D.velocity` are properties and uses a **getter**. This is means that it returns a **copy** of `Rigidbody2D.velocity` not the original variable or a reference of it because they are both structs as mentioned above.

See [reference type and value type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c) for more info on this.

**4**.When you call the `Vector3.Set` and `Vector2.Set` functions, you are calling that on a copy of a `Vector3` and `Vector2` not the actual or original Vector and this is due to **#3**.

If you really want to use the `Set` function on a `Rigidbody` create a different Vector variable you will be using to call that `Set` function on then assign the value to your `Rigidbody.velocity`.

For example,

```
Rigidbody2D body = null;
float dir = 4f;

Vector2 pos = Vector2.zero;

void YourFunction()
{
    pos.Set(10 * dir, body.velocity.y);
    body.velocity = pos;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I could design a struct property with 10 members where most of them will be set independently by design. Then I aggregate it into every class in my project and pass the development to someone who I hate.

Comment: Lol I don't think Unity meant to make people suffer with that. They used `struct` for performance reasons because they want you to be able to  `new Vector2` in a function without allocating memory. If they used `class` for this, your game would be slower if you use `new Vector2` in a function(especially the `Update`) function. Although, I think they should warn people when calling this function from a reference object otherwise a new Unity user would end up  stuck on an issue like this one for days.

Comment: I don't think that they should warn about this, it's a pretty basic concept of C# which should be learned as one of the first things of the language.

Comment: @Galandil True. It's a C# thing but Unity is known for breaking with the standard sometimes. I think that they should make the `Set` function to perform work on the current `Vector` when called from a class. They did this for the `ParticleSystem` which uses `class`. They made it so that some of the Particle structs can be used to modify class/reference. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40130332/understanding-the-struct-in-unity-particlesystem/40132652#40132652) post for example. It's not uncommon in Unity.