# Unity ParticleSystem code , how it works?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

We have that code from Unity documentation for particle system:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        ParticleSystem ps = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        var em = ps.emission;
        em.enabled = true;

        em.type = ParticleSystemEmissionType.Time;

        em.SetBursts(
            new ParticleSystem.Burst[]{
                new ParticleSystem.Burst(2.0f, 100),
                new ParticleSystem.Burst(4.0f, 100)
            });
    }
}
```

1) Is var means ParticleSystem.EmissionModule ?
2) How em affect ps.emission without writing `ps.emission = em;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var` is just a way to let the compiler figure out the Type. You could also write it out in full if you want. You can check this by placing your cursor on `var`. You should see `ParticleSystem.EmissionModule` as the inferred Type.

2. `ParticleSystem.EmissionModule` provides access to your particle system emission module so that you can manage its properties.

The documentation reads:

> Access the particle system emission module.
>
> Particle system modules do not need to be reassigned back to the
>   system; they are interfaces and not independent objects.

Comment: thanks for the clarification of the first question , the second one i didn't get it yet ;is EmissionModule an interface ? if yes i thought we can't create objects from interfaces directly if no what is it and how it works ??

Comment: You can. What you can't do is to create an instance of an `Interface`. The same goes for classes marked as `abstract`. If I have an `Istudent` interface, and a `Student` class that implements that interface, I can create a student object by doing: `Istudent student=new Student();`. I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you that's true instance is not same as object they are different things , last question how EmissionModule  instance em will modify ps.emission attributes like in  'em.enabled = true;' how it will get into ps.emission.enabled without using ps.emission = em; line?

Comment: As explained in the documentation, `ParticleSystem.EmissionModule` is just a way to set some of the emission properties of your particle system. You can't set `ps.emission=em` or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40130332/understanding-the-struct-in-unity-particlesystem)

1. Yes.
2. Simply put, this struct `ParticleSystem.EmissionModule` actually holds a reference to the `ParticleSystem`. And the getters and setters of its properties are in fact reading and writing the `ParticleSystem` object, so Unity calls it an "Interface".

But it is actually a struct and **not an interface in C#**. This behavior violates the immutability of struct and is terrible code.