# How to keep a reference to a Particle System module's struct in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, struct, ref, particle-system

I'd like to keep a reference to a MinMaxCurve, a struct in some particle system module.

I need this ability to refer to any MinMaxCurve generically, rather than always dealing with the specific module and attribute.

Here's the gist:

```cs
public class ParticleAttributeMultiplier : ParticleAttributeAdjuster {

    new private ParticleSystem particleSystem;
    private ParticleSystem.EmissionModule emission;
    private ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve minMaxCurve;

    public override void Start () {
        particleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ();
        emission = particleSystem.emission;
        minMaxCurve = emission.rateOverTime;
    }

    public override void Input (float intensity) {
        minMaxCurve = 1000f;
    }
}
```

This does not work because the [emission and rateOverTime are both structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40130332/understanding-the-struct-in-unity-particlesystem), returned by value:

```
public struct EmissionModule
{
    // ... 
    public MinMaxCurve rateOverTime { get; set; } // also a struct
    // ... 
}
```

Is it possible, in any way, to store a reference to rateOverTime as a MinMaxCurve?

---

This seems to be the crux of the problem:

```
// "A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter"
ref ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve minMaxCurve = ref emission.rateOverTime;
```

Really appreciate any geniuses out there who can solve my problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256048/store-a-reference-to-a-value-type
possible duplicate question

Comment: It's impossible, you can deal with the `EmissionModule` because it keeps a ref to the particle system, but `MinMaxCurve` doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

[`ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve.html) is a `struct` → **value type**

Just like e.g. `Vector3` the variable is stored by **value** not using a **reference** like it would the case for a `class`.

The only way is storing a reference to the according parent `class` which in your case is the `particleSystem` reference and access the value through it. You could get this reference stored by making it

```
 [SerializeField] private ParticleSystem _particleSystem;
```

and drag it in via the Inspector.

---

You can however store and adjust a generic `ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve` value via the Inspector if that is what you are looking for

```
[SerializeField] private ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve minMaxCurve;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @derHugo